# Raphael js removing an event on one object and then replacing it when a different object is selected

Tags: raphael, mouseevent

I have two questions.

I am dynamically creating circles that get placed on a map.  Each circle animates larger on mouseover and then animates smaller on mouseout.  The circle needs to stay large when it gets clicked.  I do this part by removing the mouseout event by using unmouseout() in the click handler. However, and this is where I am stuck, I need the previously selected circle (the one without it's mouseout event) to animate back to it's original size, when I click on a new circle.  I am supposing that I could achieve this by putting it's mouseout event back on it?  But haven't been able to get this to work.  Any ideas how I can do this?

Also, the circles get dynamically generated and placed on the map, depending upon the type and number of data items read from an xml.  I want to remove all of them- and then replace with a new set when a UI gets selected.  My question is how do I remove all of the elements before replacing them with new ones.

I am including my script that does what is described in the first question. It doesn't read from an .xml, but instead from an array for testing purposes. I have successfully done this with addClass removeClass and css.  Tried it here but no go. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
var arr = [[556,227,"this", "Is text that is to be the abstract"],[500,60,"that", "Is text that I hope is here"],[180,80,"another thing", "Even more text"]];
var currRect;
var currTitleTxt;
var currTeaseTxt;



 function doMe() {  
     var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 696, 348); 
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         paper.circle(arr[i][0], arr[i][1], 6)
         .attr({fill: '#fff', 'fill-opacity': 0.5})
         .data("i", [arr[i][0],arr[i][1], arr[i][2], arr[i][3]])
         .click(function () {
    this.unmouseout();
     })

.mouseover(function () {
        this.animate({ r:8 }, 250 );
    this.animate({"fill-opacity":1}, 150 )


     })
.mouseout(function () {
        this.animate({ r:6 }, 250 );
    this.animate({"fill-opacity":0.5}, 150 )

     });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you only ask **one** question per question on stackoverflow, but I'll answer them both  as you are new.

**Question 1:**

One way to maintain the clicked circle is to store a value on it, to show that it is selected, raphael makes it easy to add values using the data call.

```
element.data('someKey', 'someValue');
```

Here are my updates to your code to show an example of this in use, I added two function to handle the mouse over and mouse out states, this is to avoid repeating code. Also I changed your for loop as it was set to 5 but you only had 3 items in your array. Now it works regardless of how many you have in the array.

**Demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/Cyyxk/5/

```
var arr = [
    [50, 50, "this", "Is text that is to be the abstract"],
    [100, 50, "that", "Is text that I hope is here"],
    [150, 50, "another thing", "Even more text"]
];
var currRect;
var currTitleTxt;
var currTeaseTxt;
var prevItem;

doMe();

function doMe() {
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 696, 348);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        paper.circle(arr[i][0], arr[i][1], 6).attr({
            fill: '#fff',
            'fill-opacity': 0.5
        }).data("i", [arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][2], arr[i][3]]).click(function () {
            this.unmouseout();
        }).click(function () {
            if (this.data('selected') != 'true') {
                if (prevItem != null) {
                    prevItem.data('selected', '');
                    handleOutState(prevItem);
                }
                prevItem = this.data('selected', 'true');
            }

        }).mouseover(function () {
            handleOverState(this);
        }).mouseout(function () {
            if (this.data('selected') != 'true') handleOutState(this);
        });
    }

    function handleOverState(el) {
        el.animate({
            r: 8
        }, 250).animate({
            "fill-opacity": 1
        }, 150);
    }

    function handleOutState(el) {
        el.animate({
            r: 6
        }, 250).animate({
            "fill-opacity": 0.5
        }, 150);
    }

}
```

**Question 2:**

To remove all the elements from your paper:

```
paper.clear();
```

Obviously make sure that you can get to the `paper` variable from the function you are calling it from or it won't work.

Comment: Thanks Neil!  This is awesome.  Pretty new to JQuery, still trying to get my head around the syntax.  A couple of side questions to make sure I understand. (I know just one per- but they're related).  The .click function goes into data(), and prevItem.data('selected'', "") is the method of storing a particular value on an specific object for later use?

Comment: There is a part two to this listed below, as I ran into some issues when integrating some previous features.  Sorry if I am running afoul of SO ettiquette by doing this, but thought it might more sense to put it into context. -david

Comment: If my answer helps you then mark it correct, then raise a new question. Just delete the other part from here as it has been put as an answer not a question. Cheers.

Comment: I will entitle it "Raphael JS combined elements with separate control: Removing Event Part 2."  -david